# HTML+CSS smooth scrolling is not working with ID's and classes

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.hrefbox {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
}

#box2 {
  background: blue;
}

#box3 {
  background: green;
}

#box4 {
  background: peru;
}

#box5 {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>This is my Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#box1" ; class="hrefbox">Box 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box2" ; class="hrefbox">Box 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box3" ; class="hrefbox">Box 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box4" ; class="hrefbox">Box 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box5" ; class="hrefbox">Box 5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="box1" ; class="box">BOX 1</div>
  <div id="box2" ; class="box">BOX 2</div>
  <div id="box3" ; class="box">BOX 3</div>
  <div id="box4" ; class="box">BOX 4</div>
  <div id="box5" ; class="box">BOX 5</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to make smooth scrolling with a class (`.hrefbox`) but it didn't work. I tried with "body" tag too, didn't work either. I have no idea is this normal or did I something wrong,  I'm new at this.

Comment: It worked with `<html>` because that's the element that you scroll. Any scroll related properties are working only on element that has scrollbars and have no effect on other elements. So make your body scrollable or some container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the scroll behavior on `html`.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

See it working here:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#box1 {
  background: red;
}

#box2 {
  background: blue;
}

#box3 {
  background: green;
}

#box4 {
  background: peru;
}

#box5 {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>This is my Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#box1" ; class="hrefbox">Box 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box2" ; class="hrefbox">Box 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box3" ; class="hrefbox">Box 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box4" ; class="hrefbox">Box 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box5" ; class="hrefbox">Box 5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="box1" ; class="box">BOX 1</div>
  <div id="box2" ; class="box">BOX 2</div>
  <div id="box3" ; class="box">BOX 3</div>
  <div id="box4" ; class="box">BOX 4</div>
  <div id="box5" ; class="box">BOX 5</div>
</body>

</html>
```